# BehaviorSubject not emitting values

Tags: angular, angular7, rxjs6, behaviorsubject

In my Angular 7 app I have a login service which tracks whether or not the person is logged in and an admin.  Only the initial `true` value from the `login` method is being seen for some reason.  In the service I have this:

```js
private admin = new BehaviorSubject(false);
admin$ = this.admin.asObservable();

login(user: string, pwd: string): Observable<ILoginData> {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('admin');

    const coded = btoa(`${user}:${pwd}`);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': `Basic ${coded}`,
    });

    return this.http
        .post<ILoginData>(`${this.baseUrl}/login`, null, {headers: headers})
        .pipe(
            tap(x => {
                sessionStorage.setItem('admin', JSON.stringify(x.admin));

                this.admin.next(x.admin);
            })
        )
}

logout(): void {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('admin');
    this.admin.next(false);
}
```

And then the `app.component.ts` subscribes to that:

```js
private subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.producerService.admin$.subscribe(x => {
        console.info(`Admin being set to ${x}`);
        this.showAdminSection = x;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.subscription) {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

What I'm seeing is when I log in the subscription gets called with a value, but when I call the `logout()` method, even though I'm sending a `false` update, the message is never printed to the console saying that it's being set to `false`.  It's like only the first value is emitted and then the subscription shuts down for some reason.

I'm not sure why the `false` doesn't appear to be getting sent/received.

Comment: Seems like your subscription is getting removed somehow. Can you try commenting line this.subscription.unsubscribe(), so that we can at least identify the cause ? The problem doesn't seems to be with BehaviourSubject/ReplaySubject or Subject.

Comment: Commented it out. Still no message when I go to the logout route

Comment: While logout you are redirecting right? so If component is destroyed then how could subscribe work here? because you unsubscribed on destroy.

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham I'm going to a route, yes, but this code is in the app.component.ts file, so that never really goes away as it contains the router-outlet inside of it...at least that's my understanding.

Comment: yes correct @Gargoyle.

Comment: @Gargoyle I'm sure you've already figured this out. But if there is someone else coming here, the issue is not with the code but how the service is provided. When I changed to provide in root, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily true that `ngOnDestroy` is called before getting the latest value from observable.

It depends upon the logic or time needed to perform the operation. In your case, `logout` needs some more time, and before it gets completed, `ngOnDestroy` is called and your subscription is destroyed.

For example, consider code at here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ap9olc). If you see in **test.service.ts** file, I have created 2 functions as below :

```
...
  nextValueDelayed(value: boolean) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._test.next(value);
    });
  }

  nextValue(value: boolean) {
    this._test.next(value);
  }
...
```

Now, from **app.component.ts**, I am calling the same like below:

```
...
  reverse() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    this._testService.nextValue(this.visible);
  }

  reverseDelayed() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
    this._testService.nextValueDelayed(this.visible);
  }
...
```

Both functions are called from buttons and `visible` is responsible for creating and destroying `HelloComponent`.
**app.component.html**

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}" *ngIf="visible"></hello>
<button (click)="reverse()">Reverse</button>
<button (click)="reverseDelayed()">Reverse Delayed</button>
```

Now, `HelloComponent` is subscribing and consoling the value and unsubscribing on destroy like below :
**hello.component.ts**

```
...
ngOnInit(){
    this.sub = this._testService.test$.subscribe(value=>{
      console.log(value);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
...
```

Now, try to click on `Reverse` and `Reverse Delayed` buttons, you would see that, when you click on `Reverse`, it will print all the values. But, when you click on `Reverse Delayed`, component will be destroyed before getting the latest value, becuase, we have used `setTimeout` to add some delay.

Comment: That makes sense.  Except I'm doing the subscription in the `app.component.ts` and so the destroy is never going to happen in this case.

Comment: When you call `logout`, does it print any error on console? Can you provide your code's replica on stackblitz?

Comment: No to both.  There's no print whatsoever.  I was trying to generate a stackblitz showing the issue but because it's tiny it of course works (cause we know BehaviorSubject works properly)...so there's something else in my code causing it but I just can't figure out what.